# how do I kill idle redis clients

Tags: redis

I want to timeout and kill idle redis clients.  Is there a setting I can set to do this?  I seem to remember setting a configuration somewhere but I can't seem to find it again.

I want this to be done automatically, rather than manually calling the client kill command.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have a look into the Redis configuration file (the one you use to launch Redis).

```
# Close the connection after a client is idle for N seconds (0 to disable)
timeout 0
```

Just check the parameter is not commented out, and change the timeout parameter to put a non zero value in seconds. The instance should be restarted to take this parameter in account.

To change this parameter on a running Redis instance, you can use a client command:

```
> src/redis-cli config set timeout 10
OK
> src/redis-cli config get timeout
1) "timeout"
2) "10"
```