# How to kill idle clients opened by Node on Redis?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, node-redis

I'm having a very difficult time to automatically close Redis' client connections. It is most certainly a problem with the `redis` package:

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

Redis will keep connections alive until you close them or a timeout, that defaults to infinite, is reached.

I'm aware of this:

[how do I kill idle redis clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956010/how-do-i-kill-idle-redis-clients)

And even before reading on SO I tried to set the `timeout` config both by .conf file and by command line but none of them worked.

What actually happens is very weird:

If I run `CLIENT LIST` after the N seconds:

- The same number of idle connections are still there
- The client 'idle' info restarts from 0 (for example, if I set 10 seconds of timeout, after 11 seconds the `idle` info is 1).
- The addr changes. The port number changes as it is creating new connections to not lose that client.
- The client is actually attached to Node. It seems to be a new node process. If I keep the node app UP the connections won't die. If I close the app all connections created by it close. So `redis` module is probably 'restarting' the connection.

Any ideas on what I should do not force the 'resurection' of a killed client?

Obs: I understand I can close the client's connection with 'quit()', but I must assure it will get rid of any idle client that wasn't closed by the application after some time.

Comment: There's [various options](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#options-object-properties) to configure the client's behaviour for when its connection is being closed by the server (the default is to reconnect, which is what you're seeing). However, why is the Node code creating (which I assume to be) too many connections? Why not just one connection and reuse it? And if that's not possible, why aren't the connections properly closed by the client?

Comment: @robertklep i agree if done correctly there shouldn't be a new client opened for every request. Code is required to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: hey guys. I want to make sure, even if application fails to close the connection (now it is doing it, after I made some changes in the code), the old ones will not be alive forever. so I want to, somehow, remove all the responsibility from the application

Comment: @robertklep I read this, but what option should I change to make it no 'retry' or not 'reconnect' ? I didn't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent node `redis` from reconnecting, I passed to createClient the key `retry_strategy`.

it must be a function that retuns `false` or throws an `Error`